# How do I make jquery/ajax code to make content boxes rearrange when new content is posted

Tags: jquery, ajax

I did a quick doodle to help explain what I am talking about. I'm not sure how to make this code, i just know that i'll need jquery and ajax. 
[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with making this happen... or know of any tutorials or can refer me to the right code or functions i'd need to learn.. I want the current post to be displayed in the main big box and when new content is posted, that main current box moves to where the past cont. boxes are (shrinking to the size of the past content boxes while moving). And a new  big main content box appears with the new content. All the boxes will rearrange. and i'll have a certain amount of boxes so the last one will always disappear.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show a little effort. Have you any code?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not asking for anyone to make the code for me. I just need a.. starting point if that makes sense for this. I have my php and css and all that code but i didnt think it would be necessary for me to post that. I have no code at all for this certain thing. If I did, I definitely would have posted it to show that i'm not just asking for someone to do it for me. Just, for this, I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use jQuery for such thing.

For example you can create both versions:

```
var version1='<div><span>something</span></div>';
var version2='<div><span>something2</span></div>';
```

then you can have one div which will hold all this content and you `append()` values as you need.

For example:

```
<body>
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>

//javascript code
    var test=1;
    if(test==1)
    {
      $('#holder').append(version1);
    }else
    {
      $('#holder').append(version2);
    }
```

This is something that came to my mind...I really hope that this helps you a bit.